# Error message displayed

Tags: php

I have a two pages index.php and seat.php
When the user select `arrival`,`destination` and `date` from `index.php` page then he retrieve the value from database. The user choose value of database and then move to the next page. But I faced a problem when a user move to the `seat.php` page he can't get the date selected in `index.php` page (not show in text box).

The error message is

> Notice: Undefined index: doj in C:\wamp\www\ Ticket Reservation System\seat.php Call Stack)

here this is the code for index page:

```
<?php
    include("dbconnect.php");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['date'] = 'doj';
?>

<form method="POST">
  <td width="48" height="32" class="simpletext">FROM:</td>
  <td width="107">
    <div align="justify">
      <select class="html-text-box" ; font-style:oblique; width:100px; font-family:verdana; font-weight:bold" name="from">
    <option value=" " selected>:: Departure ::</option>
    <option value="ABBOTTABAD ">ABBOTTABAD</option>
    <option value="BAHAWALPUR " >BAHAWALPUR</option>
    <option value="CHINIOT " >CHINIOT</option>
    <td width="24 " align="right "  class="simpletext "><div align="center ">TO:    </div></td>
    </select>
    <td width="107 "  align="left "><select class="html-text-box "     font-  style:oblique; width:100px; font-family:verdana; font-weight:bold" name="to">
        <option value="" selected>:: Arrival ::</option>
        <option value="ABBOTTABAD">ABBOTTABAD</option>
        <option value="BAHAWALPUR">BAHAWALPUR</option>
      </select>
      <tr>
        <td height="32" class="simpletext">DEPERATURE</td>
        <td>
          <div data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data- date="document.write(date())" class="input-append date myDatepicker">
            <input type="text" value="" name="doj" size="16" class="span2" required><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar">  </i></span> 
          </div>
        </td>
    </div>
    <td align="right" class="simpletext">RETURN:</td>
    <td>
      <div data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="document.write(date())" class="input-append date myDatepicker">
        <input type="text" value="" name="doj" size="12" class="span2" required>
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span> 
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="34" colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">
        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" onClick="return callfrm(document.getElementById('currentdate').value);" class="html-button">
          <input type="submit" name="resert" value="Reset" class="html- button">
        </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

this is the code that i use for seat page

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $date = $_SESSION['doj'];   
?>
<?php
    $date = strip_tags( utf8_decode( $_POST['doj'] ) );
    $query = "select * from seat where date = '" . $date . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    {
    }           

    <label>Date of Journey</label>
<?php
    echo "<input type='text' class='span2'     name='doj' value='". $date ."' readonly/>";
?>
```

Comment: i can't get the value of doj on seat page.........

Comment: Please review your markup carefully there are a lot of snytax errors.

Comment: yeh i know actually i take a chunck of code from my two pages as it is imposible to display my all code because it is too lengthy(if it is possible then i email u my hole code?????)......so my question is about (doj) variable the value is not get on seat.php page

Comment: Note: `$_SESSION['date']` != `$_SESSION['doj']`